# FileManager.replaceItem removing original item

Tags: swift

I can't see a hint of this in the documentation.

When I use replaceItem

```
try fileManger.replaceItem(at: destinationURL, withItemAt: originURL, backupItemName: nil, options: .usingNewMetadataOnly, resultingItemURL: nil)
```

The file at originURL is also removed.

I can't see where it says this in the documentation.

I know I can use

```
fileManager.copyItem(at:, to:)
```

but I need an atomic copy, and replace item has the following within the documentation:

> Replaces the contents of the item at the specified URL in a manner
>   that ensures no data loss occurs.

That would indicate to me that it is a safer method to use for an atomic copy.

Comment: The documentation may be unclear, but I am fairly sure that the method is meant to be used for a “safe save”: You write the updated contents to a new file, and then use   `replaceItem()` to update the original file with the new contents. – Note that your variable names are misleading: The first parameter of that method is “originURL” and the second parameter is “newItemURL.”

Comment: I mean yes, replace can mean that. But I replaced Windows XP with Windows 10 but an instance didn't disappear from anywhere. A glib reply, but I'm sure you'll agree that replace doesn't have a defined meaning in software

Comment: Whatever the correct interpretation of the word replace is I can not see a clear question here, could you clarify what you are asking for? If atomic is important can't you first copy the file to a temp folder and then do replaceItem(at:)

Comment: The file is a bundle, and I'm about to write a separate question for that. This question is to clarify what replaceItem does, and it seems to be the prevailing opinion that it removes the original.